# Как запустить xdebug в phpstorm по symfony task?

Tags: php, symfony2

Как запустить Task в режиме отладки с xdebug для symfony.

Comment: понятность вопроса: 35%

Comment: Хороший мануал по настройке xdebug+phpstorm: http://habrahabr.ru/post/250323/ Глянь, скорее всего это то, что ты ищешь.

Answer (score 2):

Я тестирую команды используя Testing Commands. Можно почитать [здесь](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#testing-commands)
и [здесь](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#testing-commands).

Запускаю из PhpStorm с помощью жука (можно правой кнопкой Debug ... или на панели настроить). При этом "Start Listen Php Debug Connections" не обязательно активировать.

Получается как то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Конфиг настроить **xdebug.ini**:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php54-xdebug/2.2.1/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Остальные возможные параметры смотреть [тут](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings).

Почитать про xdebug [тут](http://devzone.zend.com/1120/introducing-xdebug/).

Не знаю, что у вас за среда разработки, но в PhpStorm.

Если запускаете скрипт из командной строки, то просто в Run меню выберите: “Start Listen Php Debug Connections” или на иконку телефона нажмите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь вы можете запускать такс из командной строки или запустить дебаг из меню.